# Generic ViewModel in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, mvvm

I'm following the MVVM pattern in my app. As a result I have a bunch of classes which virtually consist of the same code: fetch some data from an SQL server, save some data to an SQL server. This does not seem to be the most efficient way to do this, so I thought I should just generalise
the code down to a single SQLViewModel class which takes in any type of data model object. Right now it looks promising, though a couple of things are still causing weird behaviour, e.g. for some reason

```
var json = [T]()
```

doesn't cause any compiler warnings, while

```
var json = T()
```

stops with an **Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call. Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'** error. My real question though is this: Is this actually a good way to simplify the code or will this cause me many more issues at a later time? Would it maybe be better to stick with the one model one viewmodel pattern and for instance use an extension for each viewmodel which hosts the   shared code?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: "Is this actually a good way to simplify the code" You showed only _one_ line of code... I'm not sure how we are supposed to tell here...

Comment: @Sweeper My question is not a "What's wrong with my code question" but a "Do I think correctly about how to architecture an app question" :-) Again, what I'm looking for are thoughts on using a generic view model class instead of the one model one view model approach.

Comment: IMHO creating a `SQLViewModel`  is the wrong approach: it leaks implementation details. See Clean Architecture why this is a bad idea. Better: inject your generic view model a "Content Provider" aka "Use Case" - which is a thing that takes a value as parameter and returns a value (or error) asynchronously. A Combine Publisher would be even better - make it a AnyPublisher. That way you can test it more easily and inject mocks as you like.

Answer (score 0):

> Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call. Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

Seems like the compiler complains because it can't find [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) in `T`

Which means that your generic declaration is missing a constraint eg.:

```
class MyClass<T: Decodable> {
// ...
}
```

Without more details I can say much more than that